# WSO2 IS PolicyAdminService "subscriber"

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I was wondering about a Service function `public PublisherDataHolder getSubscriber(String subscribeId)` inside the *WSO2 PolicyAdminService*. What exactly is a subscriber inside a WSO2 Server?

Answer (score 0):

Identity Sever has concept of separating the PDP and PAP.  You can define policies in PAP and publish them to multiple PDPs. PDP instance can be a subscriber for the given PAP. By default , PDP running in the Identity Server has been already configured as subscriber. Also under policy publisher section in the management console,  you can define the more subscriber that you wish to publish policies from PAP.  You can read more detail about PAP and PDP separation from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/11/xacml-pap-pdp-separation/). Also you can find more about policy administration from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/27/xacml-policy-administration/). It contains a java client that you can tryout easily with Identity Server.